# Only show top-level links in site navigation

Tags: navigation

This seems like it should be easy to do, but I've not been able to find or work out a solution.

I'm using the Starkers theme and Wordpress 3.0.4, and my site auto-generates its navigation as per normal.  I would like however the navigation to **only show the top level pages**, i.e. not display links to any pages that are children of other pages.

This is the code I am currently using.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container' => 'nav', 'fallback_cb' => 'starkers_menu',
'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

I would like to hide the child links programmatically, but I am prepared to use CSS if someone can instead advise how to assign specific classes to the child links.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**edit 2**

I've tracked down the actual function I am using, called starkers_menu (below).  However adding depth to this, or even removing the other exclusions and just using depth doesn't work either:

```
function starkers_menu() {
    echo '<nav><ul>';
    wp_list_pages('depth=1&exclude=4,19&title_li=');
    echo '</ul></nav>';
}
```

Comment: Where does `'fallback_cb' => 'starkers_menu'` come from? I assume you use theme callled [Starkers](http://starkerstheme.com/)? I can't find such function or any calls to it there.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the Starkers theme.

Comment: `'fallback_cb' => 'starkers_menu'` does not exist in the most recent version of Starkers, so can only assume you're running an older version, can you track down that function? Perhaps add a copy of the function into the question..

Comment: Good point t31os, I've added it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had you tried `depth` argument (see [`wp_nav_menu()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) documentation)?

Also do I understand right that you do not setup menu manually and let theme generate it with custom callback that you have in your code?

**Update**

Same answer - try `depth` argument, only this time in [`wp_list_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) call in `starkers_menu()` function. It should work, unless that function is never processed and not available at the time of menu running.

Do you use latest version of theme?.. If not consider updating.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rarst - I have tried depth with no luck - see my edit in the question. And yes, I am using the theme's generated menu, I have not manually changed it yet.

Comment: Right, I've just looked more closely and the problem was solved using depth.  I hadn't noticed however that the page I was trying to hide had become unattached from it's parent, and hence was a top-level page. Doh!  Thanks for everyone's help.